# select2(...) is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use `select2` plugin in `jQuery` using Eclipse, but getting an error message saying `select2(...)` is not a function. I used following script and link tags to import jquery, css and select2.

```
<link href="fromPath/css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="fromPath/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/path/javascript/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/javascript/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Following is the running code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     
    var testData = [];
    var dataSize = 1000;

    // Instead of doing this use the AJAX call to poulate the data.
    for (var i=0; i < dataSize; i++) {
        testData.push({ text: `Data: ${i}`});
    }
    
    if ($("#selector").length > 0) {
    $("#selector").select2()({
     data: testData,
    query: function(q) {
    var pageLength = 50;

    // Get a page sized slice of data from the results of filtering the data set.      
    var paged = this.data.slice((q.page - 1) * pageLength, q.page * pageLength);

    q.callback({
      results: paged,
      more: this.data.length >= q.page * pageLength
    });
  }
});
}
});
```

Version for `select2` is `4.0.0`. I also tried following ways but still get the same error.

a. JQuery is loaded only once.
b. Order is followed:JQuery,CSS,Select2

Even then facing same issues.Kindly help.

Comment: I see typo why you have `select2()` i.e : `()`  there ? remove that brackets

Answer (score 0):

Use this CDN

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```